# Disabling cache for all browsers in ASP.NET codebehind

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I'm trying to disable cache in all browsers through codebehind. I have inserted this code into each and every one of my website pages, but still they are not always instantly updating when refreshing them.

```
Response.ExpiresAbsolute = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
Response.Expires = -1500;
Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

If for instance my page writes the number "4" from my `MySQL` database, then I'm changing it and refreshing the page, it won't always instantly change. Someone it instantly changes and sometimes it takes about 30 seconds.. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

No matter, I found the solution. All that I needed to do is disabling caching through `Web.config` - like this:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <caching enabled="false" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Enjoy!

Comment: You should probably make this a bit more local, though - it's a setting available on every page. Some pages probably don't need to be always exactly up-to-date, so you can setup proper response caching. Note that those are server-side caches, while the ones you set in your sample code in the question are only concerning the client-side caching.

Comment: All pages in my website need to be up-to-date because it's database related. Thanks anyway! ;)